# asp.net redirect to section of a different page without using # tags

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, redirect

I'm trying to get to a particular section of a glossary page without using the #section in the url redirect. Basically, I'm trying to go from page a to a section of page b where the urls should look like:

```
http://location/a.aspx and http://location/b.aspx
```

But instead of just loading page b, go to a particular section of b, which normally I would do with anchor tags.

So for example, the normal method would be:

```
http://location/b.aspx#section
```

I want to do that without having that extra bit in the URL. I thought perhaps using a session variable, but once I get to the new page, I don't really know what to code to change to that new section without again adding that #section to the url. I'm using vb as the code behind the pages.

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: You may be able to do some sort of JavaScript `.focus()` on the div of the paragraph that could force the browser to scroll like the anchor tag does.  Just spitballin here.

Answer (score 0):

You could also try [Page.SetFocus](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.setfocus.aspx) method.

Usage is as follows:
**SetFocus(Control)** or **SetFocus(String)** where **Control** is the object you want to focus on and **String** is the ID of the control you want to focus on.

*Example:*

ASPX Page:

```
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <asp:textbox id="textbox1" runat="server" /><br />
        <asp:textbox id="textbox_focus" runat="server" />
    </form>
</body>
```

Code-behind:

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
   Page.SetFocus("textbox_focus")
End Sub
```